# Adding list to a view without changing views

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, view, uiview

How can I add a list (TableView) to a view without changing views, I want to show the list over the current view but in the middle of the view, so the original view will be showed also.

I tried with label...but gettign some problems adding tableView instead of label.

```
UIView *testView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 100, 100)autorelease];     
testView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor grayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2f];         UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] init] autorelease];        
label.text = @"TEST";         
[label sizeToFit]; 
[testView addSubview:label];  
[self addSubview:testView ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer [mjpopupviewcontroller](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/mjpopupviewcontroller) link as it is according to your requirement

Comment: Thank's, something I dont understant...in this example every view his own XIB file with the design, what if I dont want to work with xib files..cant I just add tableView and then 'start' it in event and adding it to the view?

Comment: yes u can do that is a another view in xib by dragging and then go property window as it has background property. By clicking a popup opens set its opacity to 30%. Now whole view will be like transparent and its parentview is visible from it. Add your tableview and other subview in it.

Comment: Yes I tried I changed in the XIB file the tableView to be half of the frame, but its opens on all the window, I adding it with this code (I am adding it to a View and not ViewController so i am using appDelegate): AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];